# Удалить дубликаты из queryset

Tags: python, orm, django

Добрый день, имеется queryset, нужно из него удалить дубликаты:

*`example = models.Object.objects.values('name', 'photo__name').distinct()`*

имеем джоин, в результате нужно получить чтобы name и photo__name не имели одинаковых значений, как это реализовать используя Django ORM ? Cпасибо!

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, быть может поможет вот эта штука https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

Answer (score 1):

Есть решение в лоб

```
example = models.Object.objects.values('name', 'photo__name').extra(
    where=['"name" != "photo__name"']).distinct()
```

которое генерирует примерно следующий SQL

````sql
SELECT "object"."name", "photo"."photo__name" FROM "object" INNER JOIN [...]
  WHERE ("name" != "photo__name") ```
````

возможно из-за join придётся указать полные названия таблиц, например

```
where=['"object"."name" != "photo"."photo__name"']
```